# Osb 11g call rest json

Tags: json, rest, osb

I need to call a rest service from http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/?key=xxxxxxxx

Using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 and deployng on OSB 11g R1

Questions:

1 - I need to create a business service and add the end point URI, but not sure if it shoudl be:

a -  http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/

b -  http://api.brewerydb.com/v2

c -  Something else

2 - Not sure about the key (authentication)

a - It should be on the transport headers?

b - some place else?

Very basic questions, but I could not find anything.

Every sample talks about xml and xsdl, I don't have them.

I've used api.brewerydb.com, because this is very similiar call that I need to do.

I have more questions but this is a good start

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for OSB in 11g.  But from OSB 12.1.3 yes.

In OSB 11g you have to define a pure Http Business Service.  And work at low level with query-parameters and so on ..

If the payloads are XML no problem to parse and serialize them but if you are facing with JSon, you have to do it yourself.  MFL transformation can help for this.